# Programmatic Login to custom JAAS LoginModule in JSF2 web application (JBoss)

Tags: java, security, jsf, jboss, jaas

I have a CustomLogin Module on my server-side JBoss EAP 6.2.0 SecurityDomain. This Custom LoginModule requires three CallbackHandlers: NameCallback (Java Standard), PasswordCallback (Java Standard) and an additional OtpCallback (implemented by myself, for a one time password).

I now want to login to this module via a JSF 2.1 web application. I know that this is usually possible with FORM login, BASIC login, or login via [HttpServletRequest#login](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). **But all of them don't let me specify username, password and otp-value.** They only allow for username and password.

Therefore I'm seeking for a way to authenticate like with the HttpServletRequestMethod while being able to supply the three credentials.

Thank you very much in appreciation of your help!

N.B.:
I've already tried to use

```
LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("MyOtpSecurityDomain", new CallbackHandler() {

                @Override
                public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
                    for( Callback callback : callbacks ) {
                        if( callback instanceof NameCallback ){
                            NameCallback nc =  (NameCallback) callback;
                            nc.setName(username);
                        } else if ( callback instanceof PasswordCallback ) {
                            PasswordCallback pc = (PasswordCallback) callback;
                            pc.setPassword(password.toCharArray());
                        } else if ( callback instanceof OtpCallback ) {
                            OtpCallback oc = (OtpCallback) callback;
                            oc.setOtp(otp);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
lc.login();
```

This even calls my server-side custom Login Module, but somehow the login is not propagated to the webapp and the EJBs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible, at least I wasn't able to propagate or tie the JAAS subject to the HttpSession.

I finally ended up packing the OTP and password into a String and passed the two parameters username and (password+otp) to [HttpServletRequest#login(java.lang.String username, java.lang.String password)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Not the most elegant solution, but it works.